# How to not update homebrew automatically when brew install some packages?

Tags: python, homebrew

I installed python3 with homebrew on my Mac. However, the latest Python3.6 cannot work well with some packages, so I decide to roll back to the 3.5.2.

Since homebrew/versions has been deprecated，I checkout the commit in the directory: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula

```
git log python3.rb
```

There

```
commit ec545d45d4512ace3570782283df4ecda6bb0044
Author: BrewTestBot <brew-test-bot@googlegroups.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 11 06:42:06 2016 +0100

      python3: update 3.5.2_3 bottle.
```

Then

```
git chekcout ec545 
brew install python3
```

However, it seems that homebrew update itself automatically I run $brew install [Formula]

```
➜  Formula git:(ec545d4) brew install python3
    Updating Homebrew...
```

How to not update homebrew automatically when brew install some packages?
Or how to install python 3.5.2 with homebrew?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ brew tap derekkwok/python or (zoidbergwill/python)
$ brew versions python
$ brew install python35
```

If you have already installed the older version of the formula you can simply switch the symlinks to reference it using a brew command.

```
brew switch python 3.5.2
```

If you want to keep a certain version and stop it from being updated ,you can pin a formula.

```
brew pin python
```

> Also you can try this Python Version Management [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).
>   `brew install pyenv`
>   `pyenv install 3.5.2`

By the way,you can see [homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) to learn more.

Comment: brew switch doesn't seem to work despite the cellar having a previous version directory 
```~ admin$ brew switch python 3.8.6_1
    
    Error: python does not have a version "3.8.6_1" in the Cellar.
    python's installed versions: 3.9.0_1
    ~ admin$              
    ~ admin$ ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/python\@3.8/3.8.6_1/
    total 64
```

Comment: This worked for me: (run under admin user) `brew link --overwrite python@3.8` . With Python 3.9 installed, this changes python3 command back to python3.8

Answer (score 11):

Answer for the first question, How to not update homebrew automatically when brew install some packages?

1. hack code solution:

   `vim /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh`

   Add return after line

   `update-preinstall() {`

   to:

   ```
   update-preinstall() {
   return
   ```
2. environment variable solution:

   `export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1`

   or

   `export HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATING=0`

   or

   `export HOMEBREW_UPDATE_PREINSTALL=0`

if U will always work, add it to `.bash_profile`